# Cannot enable remote control for still images on Canon EOS M50

Tags: remote, canon-m

When I select video recording on my Canon EOS M50 by turning the wheel

[image]

the first menu under shooting settings makes it possible to select remote control

[image]

but when I select still images instead on the wheel

[image]

the first menu under shooting settings does not contain anything about remote control

[image]

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menu tabs for still imaging and the menu tabs for video often differ from one another. Which version of the menu you see will depend on whether the camera is currently in video mode or stills mode.

None of the items in the "stills" 'Shooting Tab 1' are applicable to video, so those items don't exist in the "video" 'Shooting Tab 1' menu.

However, the last item on the 'Shooting (Red) Menu' → Tab 1 → Drive Mode is where you find the setting to enable using the wireless remote.

To use the BR-E1 remote for still images, you need to set the 'Drive Mode' to 'Self Timer: 10 sec/remote'

You also need to have already paired the BR-E1 and the camera via Bluetooth.

It's all covered on page 14 of the [*EOS M50 Help Guide*](https://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/8/0300029808/04/eosm50-hg2-en.pdf). ¹

[image]

<sub>¹ Why the information in the separate [*EOS M50 Help Guide*](https://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/8/0300029808/04/eosm50-hg2-en.pdf) was not included in the [*EOS M50 User Guide*](https://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/3/0300029803/01/eosm50-um-en.pdf) is beyond me! It usually is included in the manual.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the the link to the help guide!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember on Canon cameras remote control (infrared) for still is activated when you set drive mode to 2 or 10 seconds delay.

Comment: It depends on the specific camera model, but most do it that way.

Comment: Do you know if there is a reason for that?

Comment: @AndersLindén, reason for what?

Comment: That you cannot use the remote if the camera is set to shoot instantly?

Comment: @AndersLindén, my idea why is: when you want to take photo instantly (usually) you handhold the camera and cover with your fingers the IR window. Other idea is engineers decide to combine two things to save one menu item.

Comment: Because I dont want to change that setting when I go from shooting with remote to instead use the camera button.

Comment: @AndersLindén, if you check Michael's answer it say the same, 10 seconds timer to use remote.

Comment: @AndersLindén Then use a wired remote that functions *exactly* like the actual shutter button.Or the Bluetooth app from a phone that doesn't require the Drive Mode to be set to self-timer, though there is probably some very small amount of lag when using the BT app.